# lambda function within map function with if but without else statement in Python

Tags: python, lambda, conditional-operator

I want to pass else statement inside of lambda function. By default functions return None,
but I'm also using map function in the very beginning so instead of passing else statement
it adds None in the collection.

```
def inRangeFilter(lst):
    return list(map(lambda tpl: list(filter(lambda x: x in range(tpl[0], tpl[1] + 1), tpl[2])) if tpl[2] == list(filter(lambda x: x in range(tpl[0], tpl[1] + 1), tpl[2])) else None, lst))

print(inRangeFilter([(1, 5, [2, 3, 4]), (2, 12, [1, 2, 3, 10]), (3, 4, [])]))
```

To give you an example:

```
returns           [[2, 3, 4], None, []]
should return     [[2, 3, 4], []]
```

**Note: Task was to write the function with only HOFs!**

Comment: That code is unmaintainable.  Give up on the vanity one-liner thing, and just write it out as normal sequential code.

Comment: The result of `map()` always has the same number of elements as the input, it doesn't filter out `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension rather than `list` and check if the element from `map` is `None`:

```
def inRangeFilter(lst):
    return [el for el in map(lambda tpl: list(filter(lambda x: x in range(tpl[0], tpl[1] + 1), tpl[2])) if tpl[2] == list(filter(lambda x: x in range(tpl[0], tpl[1] + 1), tpl[2])) else None, lst) if el != None]

print(inRangeFilter([(1, 5, [2, 3, 4]), (2, 12, [1, 2, 3, 10]), (3, 4, [])]))
```

Outputs:

```
[[2, 3, 4], []]
```

But also what was said in the comments is **very** true:

> That code is unmaintainable. Give up on the vanity one-liner thing,
> and just write it out as normal sequential code. -Tim Roberts